# Encrypt fields subscriberkey and email address in the url using a key to send a cloud page in ssjs/amp script

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, cloudpagesurl

I have 2 cloud pages and I'm navigating from 1st to 2nd (where I'm doing some additional processing). Now the problem is that my 2nd cloud page needs field values from page1 which is subscriberkey and emailaddress. And I'll have to do vice versa while navigating back I'll need same fields.

Since this is on the url and visible to add, is it possible to encrypt using a key or hide it (may be)?

Currently I'm using encodebase64 and decodebase64 function to review the fields from the url but is it possible to encode/decode with key so it's more secured?

Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use cloud page's inbuilt functionality using CloudPagesURL function. You can pass your variables to this function in first page, and the cloudpage ID and the values will be encrypted in the query string parameter.

In the 2nd landing page, use RequestParameter function to read the values safely.

```
%%=CloudPagesURL(ID_of_2ndpage, 'subscriberkey', _subscriberkey, 'emailAddress', emailaddr)=%%
```

Comment: Thank you @MatheswaranKanagarajan , this worked!